LTR footnote in first occurance of acronyms
I want to have LTR footnotes for the fist occurance of acronym and I have the code in my preamble:
\defglsentryfmt[acronym]{
  \glsgenentryname
  \ifglsused{\glslabel}{}{
  \LTRfootnote{\glsentrydesc{\glslabel}}}}

but the footnote doesn't show up until I explicitly set acronym style to \setacronymstyle{footnote}, but then the problem is the footnote is RTL and I want it to be LTR.
I am using Xepersian package. I don't know thow to modify the acronym style to have the expected behaviour.
minimal reproducible code:

\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[xindy,acronym,footnote, nonumberlist=true]{glossaries}
\usepackage{xepersian}
\settextfont{XB Niloofar}

\newglossarystyle{myFaToEn}{%
    \renewenvironment{theglossary}{}{}
    \renewcommand*{\glsgroupskip}{\vskip 10mm}
    \renewcommand*{\glsgroupheading}[1]{\subsection*{\glsgetgrouptitle{##1}}}
    \renewcommand*{\glossentry}[2]{\noindent\glsentryname{##1}\dotfill\space \glsentrytext{##1}
        
    }
}

\newglossarystyle{myEntoFa}{%
    \renewenvironment{theglossary}{}{}
    \renewcommand*{\glsgroupskip}{\vskip 10mm}
    \renewcommand*{\glsgroupheading}[1]{\begin{LTR} \subsection*{\glsgetgrouptitle{##1}} \end{LTR}}
    \renewcommand*{\glossentry}[2]{\noindent\glsentrytext{##1}\dotfill\space \glsentryname{##1}
        
    }
}

\newglossarystyle{myAbbrlist}{%
    \renewenvironment{theglossary}{}{}
    \renewcommand*{\glsgroupskip}{\vskip 10mm}
    \renewcommand*{\glsgroupheading}[1]{\begin{LTR} \subsection*{\glsgetgrouptitle{##1}} \end{LTR}} 
    \renewcommand*{\glossentry}[2]{\noindent\glsentrytext{##1}\dotfill\space \Glsentrylong{##1}
        
    }

    \renewcommand*{\acronymname}{\rl{فهرست اختصارات}}
}

\newglossary[glg]{english}{gls}{glo}{واژه‌نامه انگلیسی به فارسی}
\newglossary[blg]{persian}{bls}{blo}{واژه‌نامه فارسی به انگلیسی}
\makeglossaries
\glsdisablehyper
 
\let\oldgls\gls
\let\oldglspl\glspl

\makeatletter
\renewrobustcmd*{\gls}{\@ifstar\@msgls\@mgls}
\newcommand*{\@mgls}[1] {\ifthenelse{\equal{\glsentrytype{#1}}{english}}{\oldgls{#1}\glsuseri{f-#1}}{\oldgls{#1}}}
\newcommand*{\@msgls}[1]{\ifthenelse{\equal{\glsentrytype{#1}}{english}}{\glstext{#1}\glsuseri{f-#1}}{\oldgls{#1}}}

\renewrobustcmd*{\glspl}{\@ifstar\@msglspl\@mglspl}
\newcommand*{\@mglspl}[1] {\ifthenelse{\equal{\glsentrytype{#1}}{english}}{\oldglspl{#1}\glsuseri{f-#1}}{\oldglspl{#1}}}
\newcommand*{\@msglspl}[1]{\ifthenelse{\equal{\glsentrytype{#1}}{english}}{\glsplural{#1}\glsuseri{f-#1}}{\oldglspl{#1}}}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\newword}[4]{
    \newglossaryentry{#1}     {type={english},name={\lr{#2}},plural={#4},text={#3},description={}}
    \newglossaryentry{f-#1} {type={persian},name={#3},text={\lr{#2}},description={}}
}

\defglsentryfmt[english]{\glsgenentryfmt\ifglsused{\glslabel}{}{\LTRfootnote{\glsentryname{\glslabel}}}}

\defglsentryfmt[acronyms]{%
    \lr{\glsentryname{\glslabel}}%
    \ifglsused{\glslabel}{}{%
        \LTRfootnote{\glsentrydesc{\glslabel}}%
    }%
}


\newcommand{\printabbreviation}{
    \cleardoublepage
    \phantomsection
    \baselineskip=.75cm
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{فهرست اختصارات}
    \setglossarystyle{myAbbrlist}
    \begin{LTR}
        \Oldprintglossary[type=acronym] 
    \end{LTR}
    \clearpage
}%

\newcommand{\printacronyms}{\printabbreviation}
\let\Oldprintglossary\printglossary
\renewcommand{\printglossary}{
    \let\appendix\relax
    \clearpage
    \phantomsection 
    \twocolumn{}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{واژه نامه انگلیسی به فارسی}
    \setglossarystyle{myEntoFa}
    \Oldprintglossary[type=english]
    
    \clearpage
    \phantomsection
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{واژه نامه فارسی به انگلیسی}
    \setglossarystyle{myFaToEn}
    \Oldprintglossary[type=persian]
    \onecolumn{}
}%

\newword{RandomVariable}{Random Variable}
{متغیر تصادفی}{متغیرهای تصادفی}

\newword{Action}{Action}
{کنش}{کنش‌ها}

\newword{Book}{Book}{کتاب}{کتاب}
\newword{Window}{Window}{پنجره}{پنجره}

\newword{Optimization}{Optimization}{بهینه‌سازی}{}

\newword{function space}{function space}{فضای تابعی}{فضای تابعی}
\newword{vector space}{vector space}{فضای برداری}{فضای برداری}


\setacronymstyle{footnote}
\newacronym{DFT}{DFT}{Discrete Fourier Transform}

\newacronym{CDMA}{CDMA}{Code Division Multiplexing Access}

\newacronym{BAN}{BAN}{Body Area Network}


\begin{document}

در اولین استفاده از این واژه، معادل انگلیسی آن نیز پاورقی خورده است و اکنون واژه 
\glspl{Optimization}  
را تعریف می‌کنیم. 
واژه
\glspl{Book} 
را باز کن 
\glspl{Window}  
را در
\glspl{function space} 
زیر در 
\glspl{vector space}
داریم:


از اختصارات، اختصارات \gls{BAN} و \gls{CDMA} را وارد می‌کنیم. برای بار اول پاورقی می‌خورد. اما برای بار دوم پاورقی زده نمی‌شود.

از اختصارات، اختصارات \gls{BAN} و \gls{CDMA} را وارد می‌کنیم. 

از اختصارات، اختصارات \gls{BAN} و \gls{CDMA} را وارد می‌کنیم. 


\printglossary
\printabbreviation


\end{document}


Please share a minimal reproducible example with your question, ideally both the code and the output, so that others can help you better.

Updated my answer to match the latest changes in the question.
I believe the main issue was you had not used the defined format, and you were relying on the default configuration. Using the code below, I can get the correct output.
Also the footnote option for the glossary package is not needed and is deprecated.
Defined a new glossary, a new command to use for defining new terms, and a new format under the same name:
\newglossary[alg]{enAcronyms}{acr}{acn}{\acronymname}
\newcommand{\newacr}[3][]{\newacronym[type=enAcronyms, #1]{#2}{#3}}

\defglsentryfmt[enAcronyms]{%
    \lr{\glsentryname{\glslabel}}%
    \ifglsused{\glslabel}{}{%
        \LTRfootnote{\glsentrydesc{\glslabel}}%
    }%
 }

Removed this line as the style is being created separately:
\setacronymstyle{footnote}

Here is the full code:
\documentclass{report}

  \usepackage{hyperref}
  \usepackage[xindy,acronym,nonumberlist=true]{glossaries}
  \usepackage{xepersian}
  \settextfont{XB Niloofar}
  
  \newglossarystyle{myFaToEn}{%
      \renewenvironment{theglossary}{}{}
      \renewcommand*{\glsgroupskip}{\vskip 10mm}
      \renewcommand*{\glsgroupheading}[1]{\subsection*{\glsgetgrouptitle{##1}}}
      \renewcommand*{\glossentry}[2]{\noindent\glsentryname{##1}\dotfill\space \glsentrytext{##1}
          
      }
  }
  
  \newglossarystyle{myEntoFa}{%
      \renewenvironment{theglossary}{}{}
      \renewcommand*{\glsgroupskip}{\vskip 10mm}
      \renewcommand*{\glsgroupheading}[1]{\begin{LTR} \subsection*{\glsgetgrouptitle{##1}} \end{LTR}}
      \renewcommand*{\glossentry}[2]{\noindent\glsentrytext{##1}\dotfill\space \glsentryname{##1}
          
      }
  }
  
  \newglossarystyle{myAbbrlist}{%
      \renewenvironment{theglossary}{}{}
      \renewcommand*{\glsgroupskip}{\vskip 10mm}
      \renewcommand*{\glsgroupheading}[1]{\begin{LTR} \subsection*{\glsgetgrouptitle{##1}} \end{LTR}} 
      \renewcommand*{\glossentry}[2]{\noindent\glsentrytext{##1}\dotfill\space \Glsentrylong{##1}
          
      }
  
      \renewcommand*{\acronymname}{\rl{فهرست اختصارات}}
  }
  
  \newglossary[glg]{english}{gls}{glo}{واژه‌نامه انگلیسی به فارسی}
  \newglossary[blg]{persian}{bls}{blo}{واژه‌نامه فارسی به انگلیسی}
  \newglossary[alg]{enAcronyms}{acr}{acn}{\acronymname}

  \makeglossaries
  \glsdisablehyper
   
  \let\oldgls\gls
  \let\oldglspl\glspl
  
  \makeatletter
  \renewrobustcmd*{\gls}{\@ifstar\@msgls\@mgls}
  \newcommand*{\@mgls}[1] {\ifthenelse{\equal{\glsentrytype{#1}}{english}}{\oldgls{#1}\glsuseri{f-#1}}{\oldgls{#1}}}
  \newcommand*{\@msgls}[1]{\ifthenelse{\equal{\glsentrytype{#1}}{english}}{\glstext{#1}\glsuseri{f-#1}}{\oldgls{#1}}}
  
  \renewrobustcmd*{\glspl}{\@ifstar\@msglspl\@mglspl}
  \newcommand*{\@mglspl}[1] {\ifthenelse{\equal{\glsentrytype{#1}}{english}}{\oldglspl{#1}\glsuseri{f-#1}}{\oldglspl{#1}}}
  \newcommand*{\@msglspl}[1]{\ifthenelse{\equal{\glsentrytype{#1}}{english}}{\glsplural{#1}\glsuseri{f-#1}}{\oldglspl{#1}}}
  \makeatother
  
  \newcommand{\newword}[4]{
      \newglossaryentry{#1}     {type={english},name={\lr{#2}},plural={#4},text={#3},description={}}
      \newglossaryentry{f-#1} {type={persian},name={#3},text={\lr{#2}},description={}}
  }
  
  \defglsentryfmt[english]{\glsgenentryfmt\ifglsused{\glslabel}{}{\LTRfootnote{\glsentryname{\glslabel}}}}
  
  \defglsentryfmt[enAcronyms]{%
      \lr{\glsentryname{\glslabel}}%
      \ifglsused{\glslabel}{}{%
          \LTRfootnote{\glsentrydesc{\glslabel}}%
      }%
  }
  
  
  \newcommand{\printabbreviation}{
      \cleardoublepage
      \phantomsection
      \baselineskip=.75cm
      \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{فهرست اختصارات}
      \setglossarystyle{myAbbrlist}
      \begin{LTR}
          \Oldprintglossary[type=enAcronyms] 
      \end{LTR}
      \clearpage
  }%
  
  \newcommand{\printacronyms}{\printabbreviation}
  \let\Oldprintglossary\printglossary
  \renewcommand{\printglossary}{
      \let\appendix\relax
      \clearpage
      \phantomsection 
      \twocolumn{}
      \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{واژه نامه انگلیسی به فارسی}
      \setglossarystyle{myEntoFa}
      \Oldprintglossary[type=english]
      
      \clearpage
      \phantomsection
      \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{واژه نامه فارسی به انگلیسی}
      \setglossarystyle{myFaToEn}
      \Oldprintglossary[type=persian]
      \onecolumn{}
  }%

  \newcommand{\newacr}[3][]{\newacronym[type=enAcronyms, #1]{#2}{#3}}
  
  \newword{RandomVariable}{Random Variable}
  {متغیر تصادفی}{متغیرهای تصادفی}
  
  \newword{Action}{Action}
  {کنش}{کنش‌ها}
  
  \newword{Book}{Book}{کتاب}{کتاب}
  \newword{Window}{Window}{پنجره}{پنجره}
  
  \newword{Optimization}{Optimization}{بهینه‌سازی}{}
  
  \newword{function space}{function space}{فضای تابعی}{فضای تابعی}
  \newword{vector space}{vector space}{فضای برداری}{فضای برداری}
  
  
  
  \newacr{DFT}{DFT}{Discrete Fourier Transform}
  
  \newacr{CDMA}{CDMA}{Code Division Multiplexing Access}
  
  \newacr{BAN}{BAN}{Body Area Network}
  
  
  \begin{document}
  
  در اولین استفاده از این واژه، معادل انگلیسی آن نیز پاورقی خورده است و اکنون واژه 
  \glspl{Optimization}  
  را تعریف می‌کنیم. 
  واژه
  \glspl{Book} 
  را باز کن 
  \glspl{Window}  
  را در
  \glspl{function space} 
  زیر در 
  \glspl{vector space}
  داریم:
  
  
  از اختصارات، اختصارات \gls{BAN} و \gls{CDMA} را وارد می‌کنیم. برای بار اول پاورقی می‌خورد. اما برای بار دوم پاورقی زده نمی‌شود.
  
  از اختصارات، اختصارات \gls{BAN} و \gls{CDMA} را وارد می‌کنیم. 
  
  از اختصارات، اختصارات \gls{BAN} و \gls{CDMA} را وارد می‌کنیم. 
  
  
  \printglossary
  \printabbreviation
  
  
  \end{document}



Thanks for your comment @NEO, I tried this and it didn't work. I also added the minimal code

The answer is updated based on the latest changes in the question.

Thank you so much @NEO. It works!
